# Asterisk won't does as extension_custom.conf says

Tags: asterisk, raspberry-pi3, freepbx

I'm currently working on a project where I need to do some specific tasks using asterisk.

**WHAT I DID**

I run the asterisk through a raspberry pi and convert PSTN call to VoIP using Obi110 device. However it routes incoming calls to my FreePBX. As extension file says it comes as"from trunk" context name. So to be able to answer the incoming call and play a sound file, I followed online tutorial and as an example I used provided code to check whether it actually works. So in extension_custom.conf I wrote following code,

```
[from-trunk]
exten => s,1,Answer ; 
exten => s,2,Playback(tt-weasels) ; 
exten => s,3,Hangup ; 

exten => ste,1,Set(VOLUME(RX)=10) ; set the RX volume
exten => ste,2,Set(VOLUME(TX)=10) ; set the RX volume
exten => ste,hint,SIP/ste; hint  'ste' used for presence notification
exten => ste,3,Dial(SIP/ste) ; call the user ste'


exten => steand,1,Set(VOLUME(RX)=10) ; set the RX volume
exten => steand,2,Set(VOLUME(TX)=10) ; set the RX volume
exten => steand,hint,SIP/ste; hint  'steand' used for presence notification
exten => steand,3,Dial(SIP/steand) call the user 'steand' used for presence 
notification
```

**My Problem**

After saving that and restarting asterisk and make a call to the PSTN line phone, it still rings rather than following the commands. Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: You can check what's actually loaded into asterisk using the dialplan show command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension s mean "no extension". More then likly, that you have no any goto to that extension in your dialplan.

Use

```
asterisk -rvvv
```

Check output of asterisk when call come in, you will see context and extension used.

Also you **SHOULD not** use SAME context in custom. You should use from-trunk-custom.

Comment: Thank you so much. But still I can't figure out why that doesn't work properly. I'm no expert in asterisk. So can you please tell me what should I add to my dialplan when I want to play an audio file to the caller?

Comment: If your call come in as 12345 did, you should change exten => s to exten=>12345

Comment: I thought s will accept any call regardless of its extension? I didn't. I only used s for all these extensions

Comment: No, s is "empty". I.e will be matched only url like SIP:IP or SIP:s@IP, not match of SIP:number@IP. Common, why you triing do dialplan without reading at least part of book about dialplan?